# Moving the input file with c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to be able to enter any file in `MoveFile()` and it will move the file to this folder: `C:\folder\fl.txt`. When I enter `MoveFileA("C:\\fl.txt", "C:\\folder\\fl.txt");` Then everything works, but I need to move the first file (the one that is `fl.txt`) to folder ...

How can this be implemented so as not to always enter the file name (`C:\folder\fl.txt`) so that it auto inputs it?

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    MoveFileA("C:\\fl.txt", "C:\\folder\\fl.txt");
    cout << "Operation Succesful" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I need something like:

```cpp
int main() {
    int path_a;
    cin >> path_a;
    MoveFileA("path_a", "C:\\folder\\path_a");
    cout << "Operation Succesful" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Is your file name an integer?  Why do you read an integer? Also your MoveFile will do what you say not what you want. It will try to move the file named `path_a` in the current working directory to the `C:\\fiolder\\path_a` this has no relation to the variable path_a

Comment: My file name is-"C:\\fl.txt"  and "C:\\folder\\fl.txt"

Comment: It's hard to understand what the problem is. Do you want to save the name of the last file you moved? If you draw a flowchart, perhaps it'll be easier.

Comment: Yes, I want to save

Comment: Why not save the name in a variable? A `std::string` or `std::filesystem::path` would do nicely. The `int` `path_a` is not going to work as @drescherjm mentioned.

Comment: I'm going to try now

Comment: Do you need to do this?                                                                                    
             std::string path_a;
   cin >> path_a;
    MoveFileA("path_a", "C:\\fiolder\\path_a");
    cout << "Operation Succesful" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");

Comment: @Misha That looks copied from Remy's answer. You could ask under the answer if you have a question about it.

Comment: The "path_a" usage in `MoveFileA("path_a", "C:\\fiolder\\path_a"); ` would still be wrong as I explained in my first comment. `"path_a"` is a string literal. It does not try to evaluate a variables of the same name. `c++` does not work this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    if (MoveFileA(("C:\\"+filename).c_str(), ("C:\\folder\\"+filename).c_str()))
        cout << "Operation Successful" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Operation Failed" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Though, if you are using C++17 or later, you might consider a pure C++ solution using [`std::filesystem::rename()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) instead of the Windows-specific `MoveFileA()` function, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <system_error>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    fs::path filename;
    cin >> filename;

    fs::path root("C:\\");
    error_code ec;

    fs::rename(root / filename, root / "folder" / filename, ec);
    if (ec)
        cout << "Operation Failed" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Operation Successful" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, filename)` would be safer in case of spaces.

Comment: In the case of `fs::path` one may do `fs::path file; cin >> file;` directly without using a `string` first. That also allows the user to enter a filename containing spaces by quoting the filename.